# compile ntp without ssl

Tags: openssl, ntp

I need to deploy ntp to a very space-critical pxe-imaging-system. (Yes, each KB matters.) Footprint needs to be as small as possible, so I want to compile ntp without linking openssl. According to [the manual](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/build.html) this is should be possible:

> If available, the OpenSSL library from http://www.openssl.org is used
>   to support public key cryptography. The library must be built and
>   installed prior to building NTP. The procedures for doing that are
>   included in the OpenSSL documentation. The library is found during the
>   normal NTP configure phase and the interface routines compiled
>   automatically. Only the libcrypto.a library file and openssl header
>   files are needed. If the library is not available or disabled, this
>   step is not required.

I already tried out

```
./configure --without-openssl
```

however, this didn't help. This is my ldd output:

```
ldd ntpd/ntpd
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7706000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb76d5000)
        libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb7582000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7578000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb741d000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7707000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7419000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7404000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb73eb000)
```

The system I am compiling on is 32-bit debian lenny using openssl 0.9.8g-15+lenny16.

What is the correct configure option to compile ntp without openssl?

Comment: This seems like way too much work to save 3 MB of disk space.

Comment: The setup I am using it in are very performance-critical. The whole imaging system incl. kernel and everything only is about 12mb big, 3mb being a very big addition ;-) Hope you understand that. Nonetheless, my question was not if it makes sense, but how to achieve it. There must be a very easy way I suppose, I don't think that it should be too much work. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

By researching the configure script I found out you actually got to use

```
./configure --without-crypto
```

instead of

```
./configure --without-openssl
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
[me@risby ntp-4.2.6p5]$ ./configure --without-openssl && make

[me@risby ntp-4.2.6p5]$ ldd ntpd/ntpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd516c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003838a00000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003838600000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003837a00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003837e00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003837600000)
```

Can you **show** us it not working for you?  (Don't forget to do a `make distclean` first.)

**Edit**: yes, I do have it installed:

```
[me@risby ntp-4.2.6p5]$ rpm -qa|grep openssl
openssl-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.0k-1.fc17.x86_64
```

You have told us nothing about your distro (nor even OS, though we know it's Linux from your `ldd` output).  Maybe this is a good time to get a bit more specific?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did a fresh compililation of ntp (completely new files from .tar, not only distclean) but still got the very same problem. I added the ldd output to my question post. Can you check if you even have openssl installed on your system? If it's not there it will automatically not link to it I think. However, I need to compile on a system which has it installed.

Comment: I also added a quote from the ntp manual explaining that to my opening post.

Comment: Sorry for providing this so lately. It is a 32-bit debian lenny system using openssl 0.9.8g-15+lenny16. openssl-devel is not installed.

Comment: I don't understand why my question got closed. I could still accept your answer if you find a solution though. That would be great!!

Comment: I don't see that I'm likely to find a solution, since I can't reproduce the problem. Given that you don't have openssl-devel installed, it's a mystery to me how it's finding any openssl libraries to link against; but I'm no debian expert.  Still, I agree that I think it's a reasonable question, so I've voted to reopen it in case anyone else can find out more.

Comment: What do you get from a `dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8`?

Comment: `libssl0.9.8: /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8`

Comment: How about `grep -i ssl config.log` in the top of the build tree, and `dpgk -l|grep ssl`.  You might need to edit those into your question, rather than adding comments.